# Linkbutton is not working using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written code for comment and view more button ,comment is working properly but view more is not working, code for view  more button is mentioned below:-

My aspx code is here

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
<ItemTemplate>
    <div style="border-radius: 10px; height: inherit; padding-bottom:20px; margin-bottom:10px; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px; padding-top:10px; width: 600px; font-family:Verdana; min-height:40px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); background-color: rgb(237, 237, 237); border-bottom: 2px groove rgb(54, 51, 51);">
        Comment:
        <asp:Label ID="CommentLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Comment") %>' />
        <br />
        <div style="float:right; margin-bottom:5px;">
            <asp:Label ID="PersonLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Person") %>' />
    </div></div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LPSConnection %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT Top(@TopVal)  [Comment], [Person] FROM [CommentInterview] WHERE (([Approved] = @Approved) AND ([Interviewid] = @id)) ORDER BY [id] desc">

    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="TopVal" DefaultValue="3" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Approved" DefaultValue="Approved" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Label7" Name="id" PropertyName="Text" 
                      Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<br />

<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"  onclick="LinkButton1_Click">View More</asp:LinkButton>
```

and my C# code is here:-

```
  protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    this.SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["TopVal"].DefaultValue = (int.Parse(this.SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["TopVal"].DefaultValue) + 12).ToString();
  }
```

Problem is that my link button is not firing event when i click on it.
I don't know what is the problem and how to resolve it
Please help.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: but your link_button is not appearing here inside or outside the datalist. could you please post your linkbutton's code (script) also.

Comment: where is your link button?

Comment: I Updated it. It is just below </SqlDataSource>

Comment: try debugging and see what's wrong !

Comment: I Debugged it Before and i found nothing happened. I mean to say that it is not going to my event which i fired on link button